# Questions related to Gemfire client applications

Tags: gemfire

- Can a client be created to only receive a read-only copy of the cache
  such that the client application is not allowed to make changes to
  the local cache nor make changes that will reflect on the server
  nodes.
- I have started a process that acts as a client for a gemfire server.
  I would like to fetch all the cached data from the server at once in
  the client side of the cache and only then continue with regular
  functions of the client. Is there a way the client can make a call to
  fetch all data it is interested in and get notified when all the data
  has arrived in its local cache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use GemFire security to create a read only client. You will need to implement `com.gemstone.gemfire.security.AccessControl` interface on the server side to reject all write requests from the client. You would also want to implement the `Authenticator` interface on the server to establish the client's identity.

From the client you need to pass in the credentials using the `AuthInitialize` callback. Please refer to the [security section of the documentation](http://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/docs-gemfire/managing/security/chapter_overview.html) and [this wiki page](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/GEODE/Geode+Security+Framework) for more details.

Regarding your second question, I would like to ask if your client is capable of caching all server side data, why do you need a client/server architecture? Could you not embed the server within your application itself?